# How can I randomly generate integers in interval <-99,99> in c++?

Tags: c++

I tried something like this but this generate only in interval (-99,0)

```
void input(int array [row][col]){
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            array[i][j] = rand() % 99 + (-99);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 199 integers between `[-99 ... +99]` (inclusive).  `% 99` is only 99 numbers.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) for example something like

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distrib(-99, 99);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the "old-fashioned" `rand()` instead of `std::uniform_int_distribution`, you could also do this:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
        int rnd_val = rand() % 199 // This generates a random value 
                                   // in the interval [0, 198].

        array[i][j] = rnd_val - 99; // This shifts the interval to [-99,99].
    }
}
```